# Having .NET control databinding update dataSource fired onChange (as opposed to onUnfocus)?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, controls

By default, a property bound to a NumericUpDown is updated only when the NumericUpDown loses focus.

Is there any way I can make it being updated right away with the displayed value, e.g. when the user clicks the up or down arrow?

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your NumericUpDown control in desgin mode. Then switch to the properties window and expand "(DataBindings)". Double click on "(Advanced)", a new window opens. You'll see a drop down "Data Source Update Mode", select "OnPropertyChanged". Done.

Comment: great, DataSourceUpdateMode works fine, thank you.
even though designer support for databindings does not work, for some reason :(
but that's another problem... if you've got an answer to this one, too: feel welcome ;-)
see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988835/how-does-the-sharpdevelop-databindings-dialog-work

thanks a lot again!